# How to convert groupby object to original pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Method 1 too slow: I select rows based on 'A' values, then do self_defined_normalize and return the same-size array:

```
for i in set(df['A'].values):
    df.loc[df['A']==i, 'B'] = self_defined_normalize(df.loc[df['A']==i, 'B'])
```

Method 2 extremely fast:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(self_defined_normalize)
```

But I cannot convert the groupby object in Method 2 to the original frame. Maybe you can use some `for` iterations but then such `for` iterations can be very slow again. Or maybe you have some other efficient method instead of building upon Method 2.

Below is the output:

[image]

BTW, `self_defined_normalize` is just `array/max(array)`

Comment: kindly share data, with expected output

Comment: `df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(self_defined_normalize).to_frame().explode('B').reset_index()`

Comment: @cs95 It seems that the rows have been sorted based on A values. How to keep the original order?

Comment: In that case does `(df.groupby('A', sort=False, group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: pd.Series(MaxAbsScaler().fit_transform(g[['B']]).ravel()))` work?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you

```
df['C']=df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: x/max(x))
df
```

**Output**

```
    A   B   C
0   2   1   0.250000
1   3   2   0.333333
2   4   5   1.000000
3   3   5   0.833333
4   2   4   1.000000
5   3   6   1.000000
```

Comment: Hi, it works. But it seems preprocessing.MaxAbsScaler() in sklearn (i.e. an API as x/max(x)) cannot return the desired results.

Comment: For the data you have posted, we get the result. Is actual data different? If yes, can you provide a snippet of that?

Comment: Hi, .apply(lambda x: x/max(x)) returns results as Method 1, but .apply(lambda x: preprocessing.MaxAbsScaler.fit_transform(np.reshape(x.values, (-1, 1))).squeeze()) returns as Method 2